# How to specify timezone for an input to a cell in Apps Script for Sheets

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timezone

How can you input a date in Google Sheets with a specific timezone.  To be specific I do not want any conversion and timezone of sheet or script is not relevant I simply want to say "this date at this time in this timezone" without it automatically converting to that timezone.

example:     08/27/2021 12:15 PM EDT
should read: 08/27/2021 12:15 PM EDT
what I get:  08/27/2021 01:15 PM EDT

The sheet timezone is Central as is the Scrip timezone and it seems to be converting from central to eastern but I want no conversion I want it to read the time that is input with the timezone that is input.

Comment: Post it as a string.

Comment: I was hoping I was missing something in google that allowed addition of timezones as they were input.  The info comes in on a form and involves several fields across several timezones and the Date/Time/Timezone is manipulated on a real time basis in other pages based on the input data which must be retained in it's original form .  To convert it to text would mean then converting it back to a time again every time it needed to be manipulated and back to text to be read multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

*Seems like the issue here stems from the way you pass the values from the script to the sheet.*

When setting a value from Apps Script directly, the automatic format is chosen, hence the conversion you are experiencing.

You can either set the date value as a string from the script itself or you can later set the cell/s format from the sheet.

I suggest you go to your sheet and choose *Format* > *Number* and then choose *Date time*.

[image: sheet format]

Comment: The column formats are set accurately.  The issue is I need to input times  with several different specific timezones which will be manipulated later in other attached pages but the page keeps auto-adjusting to my timezone which then makes an incorrect adjustment to the specified time when it's manipulated later.

Comment: Like mentioned, try inputting the times as strings from the script.

Comment: So the only way to handle times in sheets as they are intended is to be displayed is to turn them into strings and then turn them into datetime objects to manipulate them and turn them back into strings again so they are formatted correctly?  This can't be right.